# InvalidArgumentError: 2 root error(s) found. (0) Invalid argument: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [665,64], In[1]: [42560,1]

Tags: tensorflow, matrix, keras, reshape, predict

[[[{{node dense_22/MatMul}}]]     [[dense_23/Sigmoid/_329]]   (1) Invalid argument: Matrix size-incompatible: In[0]: [665,64], In[1]: [42560,1]
This all belongs to:y_score = model.predict(X_test, verbose = 1, batch_size = 256)

```
from warnings import warn
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod
from tensorflow import keras, reshape
np.random.seed(1337)  # for reproducibility
import keras
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop, SGD
from keras.models import Sequential, model_from_yaml
from keras.layers.core import Dense, Dropout, Activation, Flatten
import keras.layers.core as core
from keras.layers import Dense, Dropout, Embedding, LSTM, Input, merge, multiply, Reshape
from keras.layers.convolutional import Convolution1D, MaxPooling1D
from keras.layers.wrappers import Bidirectional
from keras.constraints import maxnorm
from keras.layers.recurrent import LSTM, GRU
from keras.callbacks import ModelCheckpoint, EarlyStopping
from keras.layers import Embedding
from sklearn.metrics import fbeta_score, roc_curve, auc, roc_auc_score, average_precision_score
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from keras.regularizers import l2, l1, l1_l2
# from keras.models import Model
from tensorflow.keras.models import Model 
# from keras import backend as K
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from keras.engine.topology import Layer
from keras import activations, initializers, regularizers, constraints
from keras.engine import InputSpec

from keras.layers import ActivityRegularization
class Attention(Layer):
    def __init__(self,hidden,init='glorot_uniform',activation='linear',W_regularizer=None,b_regularizer=None,W_constraint=None,**kwargs):
      self.init = initializers.get(init)
      self.activation = activations.get(activation)
      self.W_regularizer = regularizers.get(W_regularizer)
      self.b_regularizer = regularizers.get(b_regularizer)
      self.W_constraint = constraints.get(W_constraint)
      self.hidden=hidden
      super(Attention, self).__init__(**kwargs)
    def build(self, input_shape):
      input_dim = input_shape[-1]
      self.input_length = input_shape[1]
      self.W0 = self.add_weight(name ='{}_W1'.format(self.name), shape = (input_dim, self.hidden), initializer = 'glorot_uniform', trainable=True) # Keras 2 API
      self.W  = self.add_weight( name ='{}_W'.format(self.name),  shape = (self.hidden, 1), initializer = 'glorot_uniform', trainable=True)
      self.b0 = K.zeros((self.hidden,), name='{}_b0'.format(self.name))
      self.b  = K.zeros((1,), name='{}_b'.format(self.name))

      print (modil.summary())
      return modil
      #for Testing only

def test(n_estimators = 16):
        model = set_up_model_up()
       
        X_test = np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/X_test.npy', mmap_mode='r')
        y_test = np.load('/content/drive/MyDrive/y_test.npy', mmap_mode='r')
        ensemble = np.zeros(len(X_test))
        for i in range(n_estimators):
           print ('testing', i, 'model')
           print ('model shape is', model.summary)
           model.load_weights('/content/drive/MyDrive/model/bestmodel_split_chr_GD_'+ str(i) + '.hdf5')
           print ('model shape after loading is', model.summary)
           #Once the model is created, you can config the model with losses and metrics with model.compile(), train the model with model.fit(), or use the model to do prediction with model.predict().
           print ('Predicting...')
           #  X_test=X_test.Reshape(665,-1)
           print ('testing',X_test.shape)
           print (len(model.layers))
           #  y_score = model.predict(np.expand_dims(np.array(X_test, dtype=np.float32), 0), verbose = 1, batch_size = 256)
           
           formatmul= np.empty((3,2000,4), dtype=object)
           for x in range(0, 2):
             for y in range(0, 1999):
               for z in range(0, 3):
                 formatmul[x][y][z]=X_test[x][y][z]
           y_score = model.predict(X_test).reshape(665,-1), verbose = 1, batch_size = 256)
           print("model.output_shape",model.output_shape)
           print("model.input_shape",model.input_shape)
            y_score = model.predict(formatmul, batch_size=42560)
           y_score = model.predict(np.array(formatmul, dtype=np.float32), batch_size =665)
           y_pred = []
        for item in y_score:
           y_pred.append(item[0])
           y_pred =  np.array(y_pred)
           ensemble += y_pred
        ensemble /= n_estimators
        np.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/test_result/y_test', y_test)
        np.save('/content/drive/MyDrive/test_result/y_pred', ensemble)
        auroc = roc_auc_score(y_test, ensemble)
        aupr  = average_precision_score(y_test, ensemble)
        print ('auroc', auroc)
        print ('aupr' , aupr)

test(n_estimators = 16)
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. From error, we can predict there is a incompatibility between your model and your input shape. In order to find where error raises exactly, please provide the followings; (i) your model code, (2) your input shapes.

Comment: The stackoverflow team don't allow to give details. They point out this error that error I am really tired of correcting. They are loosing on the intellectuality

Comment: # !pip install git+https://github.com/Zahlii/shap.git
import tensorflow as tf
tf.compat.v1.disable_v2_behavior()
from __future__ import print_function, division
import numpy as np
import h5py
import scipy.io
import random
import sys,os
import itertools
import numbers
from collections import Counter

Comment: did you solve it ?